# Implementation of dilogarithm function for C++?

Tags: c++, c, numerical

I've been looking through GSL and Boost libraries to find the [dilogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm), but I have not found it.

Is there an implementation available for C++/C of this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSL seems to have it: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Dilogarithm.html

<kbd>gsl_sf_dilog.h</kbd>

```
double gsl_sf_dilog (double x)
int gsl_sf_dilog_e (double x, gsl_sf_result * result)
int gsl_sf_complex_dilog_e (double r, double theta, gsl_sf_result * result_re, gsl_sf_result * result_im)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a C++ implementation of the real and complex dilogarithm function (licenced under GNU LGPL) available at

https://github.com/Expander/dilogarithm

The implementations have been extracted and translated from the ROOT package and SPheno (http://spheno.hepforge.org/).